# Angular2: Very strange behaviour, error complaining about a component that's not imported even though it is imported in app.module

Tags: html, angular, angular-cli

I am busy with an Angular2 app and experiencing something very strange...  I created a new component using angular-cli called GoodsReceivedComponent.  when I import the component into my app.module.ts and app.routing.ts I don't get any build errors but when I add the path to GoodsReceived in my app.routing.ts I get an error saying GoodsReceivedComponent isn't part of any module but it is imported into my app.module...  Any idea what might be going wrong here?

**my code:**

**goods-received.component.ts:**

```
export class GoodsReceivedComponent implements OnInit {
```

**in app.module.ts:**

```
import { GoodsReceivedComponent } from './Components/goods-received/goods-received.component';

declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ProductComponent,
    CheckBarcodesComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NavigationComponent,
    SettingsComponent,
    StockTransactionItemComponent,
    StockTakeComponent,
    spinners.CircleComponent,
    LoaderComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
    GoodsReceivedComponent  
  ],
```

**in app.routing.ts:**

```
  import { GoodsReceivedComponent } from './components/goods-received/goods-received.component';

  const appRoutes : Routes = [
{path: "settings", component: SettingsComponent },
    {path: "checkBarcodes", component: CheckBarcodesComponent },
    {path: "home", component: HomeComponent},
    {path: "", redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'},
    {path: "stockTake", component: StockTakeComponent}
    {path: "goodsReceived", component: GoodsReceivedComponent}
];
```

**my error:**

```
runtime_compiler.js:215Uncaught Error: Component GoodsReceivedComponent is not part of any NgModule or the module has not been imported into your module.
    at RuntimeCompiler._createCompiledHostTemplate (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:38664:19)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:38623:37
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:38621:45
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:38612:43)
    at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:38539:37)
    at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:38530:21)
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:27267:25)
    at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:4200/main.bundle.js:27249:21)
RuntimeCompiler._createCompiledHostTemplate @ runtime_compiler.js:215
(anonymous) @ runtime_compiler.js:174
(anonymous) @ runtime_compiler.js:172
RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents @ runtime_compiler.js:163
RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents @ runtime_compiler.js:90
RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync @ runtime_compiler.js:81
PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone @ application_ref.js:328
PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule @ application_ref.js:310
(anonymous) @ main.ts:12
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 1f81207…:52
(anonymous) @ zone.js:1428
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap 1f81207…:52
webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap 1f81207…:23
(anonymous) @ main.bundle.js:1
client:38 [WDS] Errors while compiling.
client:80 [default] C:\Users\Deon\Documents\trade-link\barcode-checker\src\app\app.routing.ts:16:1 
',' expected.
errors @ client:80
sock.onmessage @ socket.js:37
EventTarget.dispatchEvent @ eventtarget.js:51
(anonymous) @ main.js:274
SockJS._transportMessage @ main.js:272
EventEmitter.emit @ emitter.js:50
WebSocketTransport.ws.onmessage @ websocket.js:35
wrapFn @ zone.js:698
ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:265
Zone.runTask @ zone.js:154
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:335
```

Comment: Can you show the full app.module.ts? We don't even see an `@NgModule`

Comment: I suggest you to put comma in this line:    {path: "stockTake", component: StockTakeComponent}

Comment: In app.module.ts the import statement import { GoodsReceivedComponent } from './Components/goods-received/goods-received.component'; Components has capital 'c'

Comment: Thanks @JSNinja  good spot:)  Please add that as the answer so I can accept it...  The strange thing is angular-cli added that import statement to app.module.ts...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the app.module.ts file there is a typo in the import statement

This line:

```
import { GoodsReceivedComponent } from './Components/goods-received/goods-received.component';
```

should be:

```
import { GoodsReceivedComponent } from './components/goods-received/goods-received.component';
```

> Note the './Components' after 'from' should be './components'